# If a User in a database has a certain value in the table

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net

I'm trying to do is kind of some basic permissions.

So here is where I am at right now: I have a database with users, but I have a number that says what they are (Admin, Mod, User...etc, and for instance 1= User 2= Mod and 3= Admin). So I want to make an `If` statement that is saying if the current user that is logged in (or when they click the "login" button) that will determine what permissions this user will have on the next form. And I want to grab this from the database, because it is stored as a value in the table.

So more like:

```
If
    This Database Value for the current logged in user = 3 then
         AdminForm.Show()
End If
```

The `This Database Value for the current logged in user = 3 then` part is what I have no idea on what to do at all.

This may seem confusing but, I just want to do this for permissions and I really just don't know how to start off doing it.